# How to define two modules linking each other in OCaml?

Tags: types, module, ocaml

I know that we can define two types linking each other, for instance:

```
type a =
   | CC of b

and b =
   | CD of a
```

Does anyone know how to do same thing for two modules?

```
module A = struct
  type t = | CC of B.t
end

?and? B = struct
  type t = | CD of A.t
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called [recursive modules](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual021.html#toc75) in OCaml. It's a little bit unfortunate that you have to write type declaration twice.

```
module rec A: sig
  type t = | CC of B.t
end = 
struct  
  type t = | CC of B.t
end

and B: sig 
  type t = | CD of A.t
end = 
struct
  type t = | CD of A.t
end
```